# Left-clicking links doesn't work, but 'Open in New Tab' does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, href

I'm working on my personal website (building from a template) and just as I finished up, my links stopped responding to left clicks. If you right-click and choose 'Open in New Tab,' they work just fine. When you hover over them, you can see the URL in the status bar at the bottom of the browser.

I've done a fair bit of searching about this already, and it seems there may be some JavaScript that's overriding the default behavior for the  tag. I've tried looking in the Network and EventListener sections of the Chrome and Firefox DevTools, but I'm not entirely sure what I'm looking for.

I don't want to paste the code for the whole site here (too long), but you can [download it from my Github page](https://github.com/rockitude/rockitude.github.io) to try it out yourself.

Since I think the problem is related to JavaScript, here are the header and footer sections of my site, so you can see what I have attached:

```
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

<title>Mike Lipson | Instructional Technology Specialist</title> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-v=2.1.5.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">    

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,600,300,200&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<link rel="prefetch" href="images/zoom.png">

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    a.heading_link {
        color: white;
    }
</style>
```

```
    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script> <!-- Potential link-breaker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack-v=2.1.5.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

<!-- fancybox init -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    var lis = $('.nav > li');
    menu_focus( lis[0], 1 );

    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        padding: 10,
        helpers: {
            overlay: {
                locked: false
            }
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: No one wants to download your code. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: If you think one of your JS libraries might be the culprit, why don't you try removing it and testing your links to find out for sure?

Comment: `bootstrap.min.js` seems to cause it.

Comment: First, I would recommend you clean up your code.. You've got `.min.css` and `.min.js` files from BS3.0.0 and the normal ones from BS2.3.2, and you also have numerous mismatched comment blocks in your HTML. When both `bootstrap.min.js` and `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` are loaded, links don't work. With just one or the other, they're fine.

Comment: Do you use stopPropagation anywhere? Apparently there is a bug with it affecting other stuff in bootstrap: http://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The carousel API automatically catches any click on `[data-slide]` or `[data-slide-to]` elements (tags that possess the `data-slide` or `data-slide-to` argument).

And you set on one of your main containers the `<div data-slide="1">` attribute (see [index.html#L68](https://github.com/rockitude/rockitude.github.io/blob/f1b65f1cf543b64771e6438efabc2b18662ab63e/index.html#L68)) therefore any click will be catched and prevented (`e.preventDefault()`).

You can see that in the carousel plugin definition [js/carousel.js#L187](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/f219fee07b14ea1d37e197b1d80f5c7a8e3bc186/js/carousel.js#L187).

So you should either remove this attribute and use another attribute name, or deactivate the carousel API.

Comment: How do you know the OP is using the `[data-slide]` attribute in their elements?

Comment: @JuanMendes There's a link to his source and hosted website. If you remove the data-slide attribute on the live page (using the web tools), you'll see the links work.

Comment: You deserve two upvotes for following the links and chasing this down

Comment: This was totally it, thank you. If I remove the data-slide attribute, the links work. However, the carousel functionality that makes the links in the top nav work is now broken, so it doesn't automatically scroll to the right place on the page. I'm going to keep working on this and see if I can fix it.